# Sunspot Solr Reindex Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     NOT_FOUND

Request Data: "type:Product"

There is 0 records in the solr data. So of course a delete query will fail because there is no records. But it's failing and aborting the sunspot reindex entirely so I cannot ever put in data into solr.

sunspot (2.0.0)
sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
sunspot_solr (2.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should upgrade to 2.1.0 https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Afterwards, try changing `sunspot.yml` in the following way:

In **development** block, add this line:

```
solr_home: solr
```

If that doesn't work, in same file change

```
path: /solr/development
```

to

```
path: /solr/default
```

Try different combinations with these and see what works.

Comment: path: /solr/development helped. But now I can't add a document to solr. It keeps giving me a 404 error.

Comment: I found a problem with line 67 in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb I had to hard code the path to post the data to. 'update' isn't a full path and it creates a 404 error